# IntPtr cast to int causing OverflowException, why not caught by static code analysis?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, overflowexception

I'm trying to find out if this scenario that caused an `OverflowException` could possibly be something that could be caught by static code analysis.

```
//IntPtr position = ...
position = (IntPtr) ((int) position + stride);
```

The above code employs incorrect casting of an IntPtr to a 32-bit number (instead of 64-bit number), which results in an `OverflowException` when a memory pointer has a 64-bit address. This only happens on a 64-bit version of Windows.

```
position = (IntPtr) ((long) position + stride);
```

And here is the fix, casting the IntPtr to a long instead.

It seems to me like something like this could have been caught by static code analysis. However, even running code analysis with *Microsoft All Rules* returns no findings on this code.

Is there a reason why something like this wasn't raised as a finding? Or is there a ruleset that might have caught it?

Comment: the static analyzers can't know whether you are going to run the app on a 64 bit or 32 bit machine

Comment: The overflow will also only happen with some values of `position`. For example, if you initialise it like `IntPtr position = new IntPtr(1);` then no overflow will occur.

Answer (score 1):

`IntPtr` is designed to work both on 32-bit and 64-bit systems. To that end, it has constructor overloads that take `Int32` and `Int64` parameters.

You can avoid this problem altogether by using [`IntPtr.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.add(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
position = IntPtr.Add(position, stride);
```

Comment: This is interesting, would static code analysis not have been able to detect when I am manipulating `IntPtr` without `Add()` and suggest that I *do* use it?

Comment: @KyleV. I think static code analysis could definitely spot this problem, but for some reason it does not. I tried this with ReSharper, which has a pretty good collection of static analysis rules, but it did not spot this problem either.